# Are questions about competitions from the web on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I discovered the numer.ai competition and I find it quite interesting as new data sets come up every two weeks and data is very clean so you can apply your methods over and over again.

I don't find a lot of ressources (e.g. blog posts) about this competiation on the web. Is it on-topic to discuss approaches here on Data Science?

Answer (score 6):

I presume you're not asking about the competition itself but some of the problems and solving them with data science. That seems fine to me.

Comment: Right .. the data is clean - this is good, but also very "hidden" (all columns are continuous variables on the interval 0,1) ... so you can play a lot (because you have good data) but you can only "guess" because of lacking description.

Comment: I am waiting for some more remarks here before I post a question ... to be sure to be on topic.